# Reordering levels of a factor by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe:

```
example <- data.frame(
  subject = c(rep(101,12),
              rep(102,12)),
  conditions = rep(c("selfimmneg", "selfimmneut", "selfrefneg", "socimmneg", "socimmneut", "socrefneg"), 4)
)

example$conditions <- as.factor(example$conditions)
```

I want to reorder the levels within `conditions` by `subject`, such that the same levels are grouped together in this order: "selfrefneg", "selfimmneg", "selfimmneut", "socrefneg", "socimmneg", "socimmneut" by subject.

This is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  subject = c(rep(101,12),
              rep(102,12)),
  conditions = rep(rep(c("selfrefneg", "selfimmneg", "selfimmneut", "socrefneg", "socimmneg", "socimmneut"), each = 2),2)
)
```

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: in the input `conditions` column is a factor, in the output it is character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `fct_relevel`:

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

# your order
order <- c("selfrefneg", "selfimmneg", "selfimmneut", "socrefneg", "socimmneg", "socimmneut")

example %>%
  mutate(conditions = fct_relevel(conditions, order)) %>%
  arrange(subject, conditions)
```

```
  subject  conditions
1      101  selfrefneg
2      101  selfrefneg
3      101  selfimmneg
4      101  selfimmneg
5      101 selfimmneut
6      101 selfimmneut
7      101   socrefneg
8      101   socrefneg
9      101   socimmneg
10     101   socimmneg
11     101  socimmneut
12     101  socimmneut
13     102  selfrefneg
14     102  selfrefneg
15     102  selfimmneg
16     102  selfimmneg
17     102 selfimmneut
18     102 selfimmneut
19     102   socrefneg
20     102   socrefneg
21     102   socimmneg
22     102   socimmneg
23     102  socimmneut
24     102  socimmneut
```

Answer (score 1):

Order the levels in the desired order when creating the `factor` so `order` will sort them accordingly.

```
example$conditions <- factor(example$conditions, c("selfrefneg", "selfimmneg",
                      "selfimmneut", "socrefneg", "socimmneg", "socimmneut"))

example[order(example$subject, example$conditions),]
   subject  conditions
#3      101  selfrefneg
#9      101  selfrefneg
#1      101  selfimmneg
#7      101  selfimmneg
#2      101 selfimmneut
#8      101 selfimmneut
#6      101   socrefneg
#12     101   socrefneg
#4      101   socimmneg
#10     101   socimmneg
#5      101  socimmneut
#11     101  socimmneut
#15     102  selfrefneg
#21     102  selfrefneg
#13     102  selfimmneg
#19     102  selfimmneg
#14     102 selfimmneut
#20     102 selfimmneut
#18     102   socrefneg
#24     102   socrefneg
#16     102   socimmneg
#22     102   socimmneg
#17     102  socimmneut
#23     102  socimmneut
```